# Ubuntu not starting after a reboot - unable to read RDB block 8

Tags: boot, 22.04, startup

Yesterday I restarted my pc, but gave an error and won't start Ubuntu. I'm running version 22.04.1. During starting an Ubuntu screen appears for a short while, but then disappears and gives this message:

loop23: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
Dev loop23: unable to read RDB block 8
loop23: unable to read partition table
loop23: partition table beyond EOD, truncated

All other services are started in the background and are reachable from web interface. SSH also working.

I've read reinstall snapd might solve it, but it didn't.

Any ideas or does this mean that I must do a fresh install? With the risk it happens again...

Comment: Fresh install with version 22.10 solved the issue, but during installation of other software, one of the ppa's was not supported yet. Therefore I reverted to 22.04. The option for installing updates during installation was turned on. After reboot, same issue. Now installed it without the updates, this worked. So it must be one of the latest updates,  which causes it.